# define a character string containing "

Tags: string, r

I wish to define a character variable as: `a""`, as in: `my.string <- 'a""'`   Nothing I have tried works.  I always get: `"a\"\""`, or some variation thereof.

I have been reading the documentation for: `grep`, `strsplit`, `regex`, `substr`, `gregexpr` and other functions for clues on how to tell R that `"` is a character I want to keep unchanged, and I have tried maybe a hundred variations of `a""` by adding `\\, \, /, //, [], _, $, [, #`.

The only potential example I can find on the internet of a string including `"` is: `‘{}>=40*" years"’` from here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html  However, that example is for performing a mathematical operation.

Sorry for such a very basic question.  Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes is an artifact of the print method. In fact the default `print` surrounds your string with quotes. You can disable this by setting argument `quote` to FALSE.

For example You can use :

```
print(my.string,quote=FALSE)
[1] a""
```

But I would use `cat` or `write` like this :

```
 cat(my.string)
a""
 write(my.string,"")
a""
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [substr](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/substr.html), one sees that the backslashes seem just to be an artefact of printing:

```
substr(my.string,2,2)
```

gives

```
[1] "\""
```

also, the string length is as you want it:

```
> nchar(my.string)
[1] 3
```

if you want to print your string without the backslashes, use [noquote](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/noquote.html) :

```
> noquote(my.string)
[1] a""
```